How do I keep "wrapper" centered even if I scroll the page?
I'm beginner, I would like to ask how can I make the "blured gray img" always stay in the center like the image. What I want with figma
This is my code and result:This is what created but it doesn't like before image.Right and bottom sides are stuck to the browser edge.
The CSS:
html,body {
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}

.bg img {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
}


.wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #38323283;
    border-radius: 45px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #00000040, -3px -3px 4px #00000040;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

The HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>profile</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="bg">
        <img src="/img/IMG_0720.png" alt="">
        <div class="wrapper">

        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>


Just by looking at your HTML didn't you intended to put the img tag be inside your wrapper div?

Yes, I intend to put text and some image inside "wrapper".
I'm making a profile site

Bro use this code


    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .bg {
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .bg img {
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-size: cover;
    }

    .wrapper {
      position: fixed;
      width: calc(100% - 50px); /* change the 50px with your value */
      height: calc(100% - 50px); /* change the 50px with your value */
      background-color: #38323283;
      border-radius: 45px;
      box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #00000040, -3px -3px 4px #00000040;
      /* margin-top: 50px; */
      /* margin-bottom: 50px; */
      /* margin-left: 50px; */
      /* margin-right: 50px; */
    }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>profile</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css" />
  </head>

  

  <body>
    <div class="bg">
      <img src="/img/IMG_0720.png" alt="" />
      <div class="wrapper"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>




No worries bro feel free to ask any questions.

I guess you just missed to code top into your wrapper.
Perhaps you can fiddle with this?


html,body {
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.bg {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.bg img {
    width: 100%;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.cut {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    background: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    background-color: #38323283;
    border-radius: 45px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #00000040, -3px -3px 4px #00000040;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 10%;
    left: 10%;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>profile</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="bg">
      <div class="cut">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1713494500139-a0d182b60cb8" alt="">
      </div>
        <div class="wrapper">

        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>




.bg image doesn't fill the browser with your code but my problem has been solve, thank you bro!!
